# How to bind a function's "this" to a class (React Component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function `handleInputChange` that I want to write once (DRY principle), but apply it to many of my React classes. However, binding to `this` in the constructor doesn't work.

```
handleInputChange = (key, value) => {this.setState(key: value)}

class Login extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                loginBox: {
                    username: "",
                    password: ""}
            }


      this.handleInputChange = handleInputChange.bind(this) // DOESN't WORK
}}
```

Why does the above method not work?
The error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

I am currently using this function wrapper workaround, but I'd rather bind the function directly.

```
handleInputChange = (_this) => () => (key, value) => {_this.setState(key: value)}
class Login extends Component {
    ...
    this.handleInputChange = (key, value) => handleInputChange(this)(key, value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind `this` in arrow functions. `this` falls through to the parent scope.

You could make it a non-arrow function:

```
function handleInputChange(key, value) { this.setState(key: value) }
```

But I'd suggest making it a method on the class. Defining a function that references `this` is tricky to read, because you never know what `this` will be when it executes, making it hard to read the function at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

arrow functions do not have their own this, if you use `call([this obj], args)`, `apply([this obj], args)`, Any "this" argument is ignored. I guess the same applies to `bind(obj)`, it doesn't bind this to the object you provided because it doesn't have its own this.

`this` inside arrow functions is decided by `this` in the lexical scope where the arrow function is defined. If you define your `handleInputChange` in global scope, `this` inside is the global object(in browser it's window), that's the reason you get the error.

If you want to use `bind`, you can define the function like this

```
function handleInputChange(key, value) { this.setState(key: value) }
```

When you call `bind`, `this` will be set to the object you provided in `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling this function inside the class, it's better to define it as a method within the class instead of defining it outside, so that the `this` issue is less of a, well, issue.

Inside the class makes it fairly straightforward:

```
constructor(props) {
this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
}

handleInputChange() {
   //Code
}
```

Or if you want to avoid having to do the messy `bind` method, you can use an arrow function for the method:

```
handleInputChange = () => {
  console.log('This is: ', this);
}
...

render() {
  return(
    <button onClick={this.handleInputChange}>Click</button>
   );
}
```

Reference [react handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)